# Add element to a nested dict where the value is a list of vector

Tags: python

I have a nested dict `a` and a vector b=[1,2,3].

```
a= {0: {0: [0], 1: [0, 1]}}
```

I want to add `b` to `a`:

```
a= {0: {0: [0],[1,2,3], 1: [0, 1]}}
```

I tried: `a[0].append([1,2,3])` and `a[0][0].append([1,2,3])`

Neither one is correct.

Comment: I get a syntax error with the line: `a= {0: {0: [0],[1,2,3], 1: [0, 1]}}`. You won't be able to get this programmatically.

Comment: Do you want to make `[0][0]` into a list of lists?

Answer (score 0):

If you want `a[0][0]` to be a list of lists, use this assignment:

```
a = {0: {0: [0], 1: [0, 1]}}
b = [1,2,3]
a[0][0] = [a[0][0], b]
print(a)
# {0: {0: [[0], [1, 2, 3]], 1: [0, 1]}}
```

To add a list of lists `lst_of_lsts`, instead of a simple list `b`:

```
a = {0: {0: [0], 1: [0, 1]}}
lst_of_lsts = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
a[0][0] = [a[0][0]] + lst_of_lsts 
print(a)
# {0: {0: [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], 1: [0, 1]}}
```

Comment: is exactly what i need but when i have a set of vectors to be added how that can be done?

Comment: @charafeddine Could you please edit the question with the example of the input? I assume by a set of vectors you mean a list of lists (instead of a single list `b`)?

Comment: this is my nested dict   `a={0: {0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0,5], 3: [0, 4]},
   1: {0: [1, 0], 1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 3]},
2: {0: [1, 0], 1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 3],4: [1, 4]}};` Now I want to add a set of vector `v1=[1,2,3], v2=[3,4,5].........., Vn[x,x,x]`,   for example add V1,V2,V3 to a like that `a={0: {0: [ [0],V1,V2], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0,5], 3: [0, 4]},
   1: {0: [1, 0], 1: [1], 2: [[1, 2],V3], 3: [1, 3]},
2: {0: [1, 0], 1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 3],4: [1, 4]}};`

Comment: @charafeddine Sorry, but your comment is not clear to me. I recommend either editing the original question, or, perhaps even better, asking a new question **specifically** about adding a set of vectors. Please include both the inputs (was `a` and `b`) and the desired output.

Comment: I have a nested dict and i want that the value must be a list of vector like that     
 `MYDisct= {0: {0: [ [0], [1, 2, 3] ] } }`

Answer (score -1):

You can't have two values to one key.
`{0: [0], [1, 2, 3]}` is not correct.

Try using a list for this:
`{0: [[0], [1, 2, 3]]}`

Comment: yes i want to use a dict of list  {0: {0: [[0], [1, 2, 3]], 1: [0, 1]}} like that

Comment: so `a` needs to be in the beginning `{0: {0: [[0]], 1: [0, 1]}}` and then you can append to that list what you wanted

Answer (score -1):

First of all, in order to add `b` to `a` you need a key. If you use

```
a[0]['b'] = b
```

Result will be:

```
{0: {0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 'b': [1,2,3]}}
```

To answer your question more specifically, I need to know how you will add that vector.